# Get location of file in an Assembly

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

In my project I have added an EXE file that I need to run. So I need the path of the exe file..

I have set properties of EXE file as "Embeded Resource" and "CopyAlways" so that it on builing the solution the file is copied to bin/Debug or bin/Release folder.

I want to get the location of file from the Main Projects assembly and pass the path(string) to a program that will run the EXE.

by doing this I dont have to worry about the location of the EXE file as it always be copied to bin folder...

**How can I get that path??**

Comment: By both embedding it and copying it, you now have two copies. I would recommend that you not set it as an embedded resource.

Comment: Thanks Dark. I will look into this. but this does not solve my problem..

Comment: Things in comments generally aren't intended to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the path to the executing assembly, you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`. You can then manipulate this with `System.IO.Path` to build the path to the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

```
string exeName = "MyApp.exe";
string fullFileName = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, exeName);
```